# Can CNTLM be configured to passthrough? Trying to achieve zero-configuration proxy switching for browsers, ssh, and the like

Tags: proxy, ntlm

My primary laptop shuttles between two office wifi environments (one behind an NTLM proxy and one require Cyberoam authentication) and various wifi/LAN environments.

My network connectivity is managed by netctl[1], with a home-brew script which does the following:-

1. Check if I'm in the NTLM office environment. If so, start cntlm[2].
2. Check if I'm in the Cyberoam office environment. If so, start crclient[3] with the appropriate configuration variables.

After this I modify a current_proxy config file and a proxy.pac file according to the current environment (basically set an empty proxy and a direct passthrough proxy.pac for everything except the NTLM environment, where instead I'd set them to point to cntlm).

The current_proxy config file is sourced by my shells (as well as by launch scripts for my various internet-dependent apps like dropbox, skype,  hubic, chromium, etc.). Firefox's connection depends on the proxy.pac file.

This works, though it's not too smooth. In particular it discourages me from simply putting my laptop to sleep, as firefox would need a proxy.pac reload, and basically all applications need to be restarted with a move between network environments. Another big issue is that I need two ssh configurations for every ssh target, one with corkscrew (for the NTLM environment) and one without.

So my questions, in order:-

1. Is it possible to use CNTLM with some sort of configurable passthrough. Such that all my apps simply expect a proxy at localhost:3128 and a CNTLM restart is all that's needed to switch from 'direct' connectivity to connecting through an NTLM proxy at my office.
2. Failing that, is it possible (and fairly easy) to use iptables to configure (on the fly) all traffic to either go through cntlm or not.
3. If both the above are not possible, would running a local squid (or similar) proxy allow for what I'm trying to do?

[1] - https://git.archlinux.org/netctl.git/

[2] - http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/

[3] - https://www.cyberoam.com/cyberoamclients.html

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I wrote a script that switches between the different CNTLM configurations (cp / restart). To not use an external proxy I just put a * in the noproxy line.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you can do is script a change to your cntlm.conf to update the NoProxy line. I haven't tried it (yet) but this blog post has an example:

http://mirkoweber.blogspot.com/2011/10/using-cntlm-in-changing-environment.html

Answer (score 0):

I ended up setting up a simple squid proxy to run on 3128 (cntlm as well), directing all my networked applications to use a proxy on 3128, and then stopping/starting the right proxy server when needed.

So far the only downsides have been when squid bugs out with certain types of activity (npm update for example), but that's long-term not an issue.